# C# XDocument - Get value of an attribute in an XML file

Tags: c#, xml, linq, visual-studio-2017

Here is my code so far:

```
XDocument document = XDocument.Load("C:\\modinfo.xml");

        var elements = from r in document.Descendants("Mod")
                       select new
                       {
                           Author = r.Element("Author").Value,
                           Description = r.Element("Description").Value
                       };

        foreach (var r in elements)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("AUTHOR = " + r.Author + Environment.NewLine + "DESCRIPTION = " + r.Description);
        }
```

---

And this is my "modinfo.xml" file:

```
<Mod Name="Mod Name">
  <Author>Author Name</Author>
  <Description>Description Text</Description>
</Mod>
```

---

At the moment, it looks like

[image: this]

when I run the application. What I am trying to do is for it to also print "Mod Name" in it also.

Comment: I have used that however. I'm not a complete expert on how to make these things work with what I've done. It only just gives an error when using that line of code given in the answer.

Comment: Is that your **exact** XML file?

Comment: Yes, that is everything that is in my XML file, and the one I am using.

Comment: Actually, no it wasn't. I'm so dumb! I've been editing the wrong file, sorry for that.

I thought that I was editing the one I was using in my project..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select the Mod Name in your anonymous type:

```
 var elements = from r in document.Descendants("Mod")
                       select new
                       {
                           ModName = r.Attribute("Name").Value,
                           Author = r.Element("Author").Value,
                           Description = r.Element("Description").Value
                       };

foreach (var r in elements)
{
    Console.WriteLine("MOD Name = " + r.ModName + Environment.NewLine +  "AUTHOR = " + r.Author + Environment.NewLine + "DESCRIPTION = " + r.Description);
}
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when using that:

"System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

System.Xml.Linq.XElement.Attribute(...) returned null."

Comment: Then you have elements without the name set. Try  ModName = r.Attribute("Name").Value ?? "Not Set",

Comment: It worked, thanks. I accidentally was editing the wrong file and had something different in both files. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your complete xml, following should help you as you do not have multiple Mods.

```
XElement xmlTree = XElement.Parse(str);  
var result = new {
    Author = xmlTree.Element("Author").Value,
    Description = xmlTree.Element("Description").Value,
    Name =xmlTree.Attribute("Name").Value
};
```

Input

```
<Mod Name="Mod Name">
  <Author>Author Name</Author>
  <Description>Description Text</Description>
</Mod>
```

Output

```
Author : Author Name 
Description : Description Text 
Name :Mod Name
```

Comment: Thanks! Already got a different answer however, I was editing the wrong file. All fixed now! Sorry for wasting your time.